# Fabric8 stuck on stop and remove docker containers

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, docker, fabric8

Hi I have a small project that I want to test some of the environment variables so I used fabric8 to build and start a docker Postgres and set some of the environment variables but when the integration tests run and pass fabric8 have a hard time to stop and remove docker container this is my pom.xml with fabric8

```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.30.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showLogs>true</showLogs>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>postgres:alpine</name>
                            <alias>wa</alias>
                            <run>
                                <env>
                                    <POSTGRES_USER>wa</POSTGRES_USER>
                                    <POSTGRES_PASSWORD>wa</POSTGRES_PASSWORD>
                                    <POSTGRES_DB>wa</POSTGRES_DB>
                                </env>
                                <wait>
                                    <log>(?s)database system is ready to accept connections.*database system is ready to accept connections</log>
                                    <time>20000</time>
                                </wait>
                            </run>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-it-database</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>remove-it-database</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and when the goal stop is called here what happens

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.30.0:stop (remove-it-database) @ chatreminderbot ---
wa> 2019-04-25 10:30:27.960 UTC [1] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
wa> 2019-04-25 10:30:27.965 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 47) exited with exit code 1
wa> 2019-04-25 10:30:27.965 UTC [42] LOG:  shutting down
wa> 2019-04-25 10:30:28.022 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

and it sticks there forever the weird thing is that it happens only some times the percent of it is like 80%